# Mix of GRUB and GRUB2 (Linux and Solaris)

Tags: linux, grub, solaris, grub2

ALL,
I have a DELL laptop on which I installed Linux and Open Solaris (in that order).

Linux used GRUB2 and it was OK. Solaris still uses GRUB1 and it looks like it did overwrite the GRUB2 installation, not detecting that there is already bootloader.

Now, this is what I have on the disk:

```
partition table: gpt
Number  Start      End        Size        File System    Name      Flags
1       1.00MiB    3.00MiB    2.00MiB                    grub      bios-grub
2       3.00MiB    131MiB     128MiB      ext2           boot
3       131MiB     2000MiB    2000MiB     swap           swap
4       2000MiB    250000MiB  248MiB      ext4           root
5       250000MiB  500000MiB  250MiB      Solaris        Solaris
```

Now my question would be: if I boot up Linux CD and re-issue grub-install, will grub understand that there is a copy of GRUB{1} and won't overwrite it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

GRUB2 will scan the disk (like GRUB) before writing the MBR. The deference is that GRUB2 implements more file systems than GRUB, so it will be able to find the Linus installation. GRUB2 will overwrite the MBR from GRUB.

Also, I found a [utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) that loads Linux and only runs GRUB so you don't need to do the full installation again.

Comment: so GRUB2 will overwrite the GRUB-1 that was installed by Solaris IIUC you response? My idea is to have a dual-boot system with Linux and Solaris... Thank you.